# Google's suggest random php

Tags: php

I want get random suggest from google suggest;
but i see

'selena','selena gomez','selena','selena gomez age','selena gomez songs','selena gomez movies','selena gomez puma','selena gomez 2018','selena gomez new song','selena gomez net woth','selena gomez albums'

do not work random:

```php
$suggURL =
    'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q=' .
    urlencode("selena");
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "http" => array(
        "header" =>
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
    ),
));
$data = file_get_contents($suggURL, false, $context);
//$data=$this->get_web_page( $suggURL );
$data = preg_replace('/]/', '', $data); // remove numbers
$data = str_replace('[', "", $data);
$data = str_replace('r', "", $data);
$data = str_replace('"', "'", $data);

$data;
$a = ['' . $data . ''];
echo "<br/>";
echo $website = $a[mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1)];
"\n";
```

Comment: Seems like it's working for me. Please provide the expected output and your actual output and why it isn't working for you.

Comment: i want get  1 random suggest  but i see 'selena','selena gomez','selena','selena gomez age','selena gomez songs','selena gomez movies','selena gomez puma','selena gomez 2018','selena gomez new song','selena gomez net woth','selena gomez albums'

Comment: Please double check this code $a = ['' . $data . '']. It will always create an array with only one index,  when you say mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1), it will find a random number between 0 and 0

Comment: Step 1: Stop messing around with JSON data using regular expressions … use json_decode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` variable contains a JSON string, so you're handling it in the wrong way. Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead.

```
<?php

$suggURL =
    'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q=' .
    urlencode("selena");
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "http" => array(
        "header" =>
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
    ),
));
$data = file_get_contents($suggURL, false, $context);

$a = json_decode($data);

echo "<br/>";
echo $a[1][mt_rand(0, count($a[1]) - 1)];
"\n";

?>
```

Explaination:

`$data` has this format:

```
["selena",["selena gomez","selena","selena gomez age","selena gomez songs","selena movie","selena gomez movies","selena gomez net worth","selena death","selena songs","selena gomez back to you"]]
```

It's JSON format, so using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you'll have this result for `print_r($a);`:

```
Array ( [0] => selena [1] => Array ( [0] => selena gomez [1] => selena [2] => selena gomez age [3] => selena gomez songs [4] => selena movie [5] => selena gomez movies [6] => selena gomez net worth [7] => selena death [8] => selena songs [9] => selena gomez back to you ) )
```

You can now access `$a[1]` which is the array of the suggestions, and have a random suggestion from `echo $a[1][mt_rand(0, count($a[1]) - 1)];`

Comment: tank u so much. I hope things will work out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check the array is processed properly, you can pick random value from the array using below code

```
$rant = $data[1][ mt_rand(0, count($data[1])-1 ) ];
```

Here is the working example;

```
$data = ["saleena",["saleena","saleena meaning","saleena saleena","saleena clarence","saleena khan","selena gomez songs","saleena shaheen aricent","saleena name meaning","selena songs","selena gomez status"]];
$rant = $data[1][ mt_rand(0, count($data[1])-1 ) ];
```